# For or if function does not work together with macro in apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, slack

I'm building a bot that connects with slack software through an API inside google spreadsheet through apps script, the purpose of this bot is to send automatic messages when an X value inside a column in the spreadsheet is true (it's a string value already defined) , I tried to use the `if` with this value but it didn't work, it ignores all the other rows of the column and goes through only one, and I tried to use the for in conjunction with the macro, recording the period of the worksheet with the filter of the specific value. I don't have anything else in mind that could help, I'll leave my code with some modifications below

```
function requestSlack(method, endpoint, payload) {
    const base_url = "https://slack.com/api/"
    const headers = {
      'Authorization': "Bearer " + "MYTOKEN",
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    var options = {
      headers: headers,
      method: method,
      payload: payload
    }
    let request_url;
      if (method == "POST") {
      request_url = base_url + endpoint
      options.payload = JSON.stringify(payload)
    } else {
      request_url = base_url + endpoint
    }
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(request_url, options).getContentText();
    const json = JSON.parse(response);
    return {
      response_code: json.ok,
      response_data: json
    }
}
function chamaMensagem() {
  let send = getDados();
    var payload = {
     "channel": "MYCHANNEL",
      "text": `*Titulo da tarefa:* ${send.TituloTarefa[0]}` +
      `\n*Proprietario:* ${send.ProprietarioTarefa[2]}` +
      `\n*Deadline:* ${send.DataConclusao[1]}` +
      `\n*Descrição:* ${send.DescricaoTarefa[1]}` +
      `\n*Status* ${send.colunastatus[5]}`,
       "charset": "application/json"
    }
   var response = requestSlack("POST", "chat.postMessage", payload);
}

function getDados(){

  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var guiadados = planilha.getSheetByName("MYSPREADSHEET");
  var linhainicial = 12;
  var colunainicial = 3;
  var totalcolunas = 6;
  var ultimalinha = guiadados.getLastRow() - (linhainicial - 11);

  var dados = guiadados.getRange(linhainicial, colunainicial, ultimalinha, totalcolunas).getValues();

  var colunastatus = 5;

  for(var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++){

    if(dados[i][colunastatus] == "Vencido" ){
      Logger.log("Já Vencidos");
    }else{
      Logger.log("A vencer");
    }

    

  }

  
}
```

Comment: getDados() is not returning anything so this function chamaMensagem() is not going to work

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (describe the relevant parts of the spreadsheet structure, add some sample data and the corresponding expected result(.